# dimensions of subspaces in R^4

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, systems-of-equations

Let $k  \in R$ e $W_k\subset R^4$ a subspace of $R^4$ given by the solution of the linear system:
$$W_k  \begin{cases}X-Y-Z=0\\
X-Z=0 \\kX+kY=0\end{cases}$$

I have to determine a base of $W_k$.

I've tried considering that k can be $0$ or $\ne 0$

If $k=0$ 
$$\begin{cases}Y=0\\
X=Z \end{cases}$$
$W_k=((s,0,s,t)|s,t \in R)$ , $dim W_k=2$ and a base of $W_k$ is $((0,0,0,1), (1,0,1,0))$

If $k\ne 0$ 
$$\begin{cases}Y=0\\Z=0\\
X=0 \end{cases}$$
$W_k=((0,0,0,t)|t \in R)$ , $dim W_k=1$ and a base of $W_k$ is $((0,0,0,1)$

Now I'm trying to solve the same problem with matrices.
The matrix of the coefficients is
$$\begin{Bmatrix} 1 & -1 & -1 & 0 \\ 1 & 0 & -1 & 0 \\k & k & 0 & 0  \end{Bmatrix}$$

$$\begin{vmatrix} 1 & -1 \\ 1 & 0 \end{vmatrix}=1 \ne 0$$
$$\begin{vmatrix} 1 & -1 & -1 \\ 1 & 0 & -1 \\ k & k & 0 \end{vmatrix}=k $$

$$dim W_k = \begin{cases}2 & if k =0\\3 & if k \ne 0\end{cases}$$
Where am I making mistakes?

Comment: It is not clear: is $k$ an unknown, like $X$, $Y$ and $Z$, or a parameter?

Comment: @Alex M.k is a parameter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The system matrix is indeed $\begin{pmatrix} 1 & -1 & -1 & 0 \\ 1 & 0 & -1 & 0 \\k & k & 0 & 0  \end{pmatrix}$. The $4$-th column stands for the unknown $T$ which is "invisible" in the system (with $X$, $Y$ and $Z$ "visible").

If $k = 0$ then, indeed, the rank is $2$, given by the determinant $\begin{vmatrix} 1 & -1 \\ 1 & 0 \end{vmatrix}=1 \ne 0$. The dimension of the space of solutions ("the number of free parameters") is **the number of unknowns minus the rank**, i.e. $4-2 = 2$, exactly as you get.

If $k \ne 0$ the whole determinant is indeed $k$, so the rank is $3$, therefore the space of solutions has dimension $4-3 = 1$ (not $3$, as you get).

These results coincide with what you have got in the first ("naive") approach (which is correct).

Maybe you thought that the dimension of the space of solutions is the rank of the system matrix? This would explain your mistake.